# Is this prior art to Power-over-Ethernet based LED lighting or illumination?

Tags: prior-art, us20080197790, us20120223650, us20120271477

UK based Convertertechnology have dated their Power-Over-Ethernet based LED lightning reference system in 29th December, 2006.

Here is the link to the document: http://www.convertertechnology.co.uk/index.php?s=file_download&id=10

The following web page seems to indicate that the document was published in 11 February, 2007:
http://www.convertertechnology.co.uk/index.php?id=53

The document itself shows clearly that their design implements PoE detection and classification.

Links:

[US20080197790](http://www.google.com/patents/US20080197790)

[US20120223650](http://www.google.com/patents/US20120223650)

[US20120271477](http://www.google.com/patents/US20120271477)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The '790 application went abandoned at the USPTO in June for not responding to an office action. The '650 application cites the converter technology device in its Information Disclosure Statement to the patent office. ( item #4 in non-patent literature )

See the image file wrappers in [USPTO Public PAIR.](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair)

The last application seems to claim a system where the light is controlled by data received over the data stream.

> 1. A Power over Ethernet-Internet Protocol (PoE-IP) Illuminator comprising:
>
>    a power/data separator, separating data and power received from a PoE LAN cable;
>
>    a DC/DC circuit, converting said separated power to voltage required to power controller;
>
>    a controller, receiving data and controlling driver in response to said received separated data;
>
>    an IP-ID non-volatile memory, providing IP-ID to said controller;
>
>    a driver, receiving commands from said controller and controlling said separated power supplied to at least one LED light source; and
>
>    at least one LED light source, producing illumination light.

I do not see that in the reference you link to.

Comment: Thanks, I believe your answer clarifies the situation to me.  --Pekka